# Javascript Conditional Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, hidden

I have two input

```
<select class="form-control" name="vat_cond" id="condSelect" required>
<option value="YES"> YES </option>
<option value="NO" selected> NO </option>
</select>
```

and

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-2" id="otherType">
<label class="text-light-blue">VAT (%):</label>
<input type="number" name="vat_cent" step="any" class="form-control" value="10" min="1" max="100"/>
```

the JS like these:

```
   $('#condSelect').on('change',function(){
      if( $(this).val()==="NO"){
      $("#otherType").hide()
      }
      else{
      $("#otherType").show()
      }
   });
```

My problem is, I need those div tag is hidden for the first time page reloaded because 'NO' is selected.
The condition right now is only hidden if I select 'YES' first then change it to 'NO'...
Any Coder Guardian can help me, please ???

Comment: try <div class="form-group col-xs-2" id="otherType" style="display: none;"> if the default is 'NO' when page loads

Answer (score 1):

You can just trigger the event on pageload

```
$('#condSelect').on('change',function(){
    if( $(this).val()==="NO"){
        $("#otherType").hide()
    } else {
        $("#otherType").show()
    }
}).trigger('change');
```

you could also use jQuery's `toggle()` to shorten it a bit

```
$('#condSelect').on('change',function(){
    $("#otherType").toggle( this.value !== "NO" );
}).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Mr. Adeneo, you dont only help me, Sir. U also make my life easier!

Comment: @adeneo instead of triggering the event what if we set it hidden by default buddy

Comment: @MehravishTemkar - sure, in this case it's a simple visibilty toggle, so just hiding the element to begin with would work fine as well.

Comment: <div class="form-group col-xs-2" id="otherType" style="display: none;"> this would simply avoid the the event to be triggered i guess @adeneo